# Set NavigationBar hidden the search is no longer available

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I try to use the new .searchable feature. The following code works as expected:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

   @State private var searchText = ""

   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .navigationTitle("Title")
//        .navigationBarHidden(true)
       }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       ContentView()
    }
 }
```

If you remove the  comment, the searchbar is no longer available. Any idea why this happens and how to avoid this?

Comment: Because the placement of the search field for `.searchable() is in the .navigationBarDrawer`, `.sidebar` or `.toolbar`, all of which are hidden with `.navigationBarHidden(true)`.

Comment: Do you know if there is a workaround?

Comment: Roll your own search bar. There are tons of examples. If you want `.searchable()` you have to have a navigation bar. What is the issue with the navigation bar?

Comment: I have a static element on top off the screen. (see here: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/086sZp6woQHvkZ2j5kz7HPWLA#Simulator_Screen_Shot_-_iPhone_13_mini_-_2021-11-19_at_17.27.56). The list below has exact the right behaviour I desired. I have solved the problem by adding a search button. Thanks for your support.